# How can I remove @link tag and its contents between { and } from a javadoc comment?

Tags: python, regex, javadoc

I am trying to analyse Javadoc comments. I do not need the contents of `@link` tag. How can I remove this? 
The general format is `{@link.........}`

With this code below, I get an error: `ValueError: unexpected '{' in field name`

```
with open("comments.txt", 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
           remove_link_tag = re.sub('{@link(.*?)}', lambda m: " 
              {@link{}}>".format(                                                    
                m.group(1).replace(".", "").replace(",",                                                                                                     
                  "").replace(";",                                                                                                                 "")), line, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

INPUT:

```
/**
    * Adds the specified source and target vertices to the graph, if not already included, and
    * creates a new edge and adds it to the specified graph similarly to the
    * {@link Graph#addEdge(Object, Object)} method.
    * {@code sourceVertex}
    * @param graph the graph for which the specified edge to be added
    * @param sourceVertex source vertex of the edge
    * @param targetVertex target vertex of the edge
    * @param <V> the graph vertex type
    * @param <E> the graph edge type
    *
    * @return The newly created edge if added to the graph, otherwise <code>
    * null</code>.
    */
```

OUTPUT

```
/**
    * Adds the specified source and target vertices to the graph, if not already included, and
    * creates a new edge and adds it to the specified graph similarly to the
    * method.
    *
    * {@code sourceVertex}
    * @param graph the graph for which the specified edge to be added
    * @param sourceVertex source vertex of the edge
    * @param targetVertex target vertex of the edge
    * @param <V> the graph vertex type
    * @param <E> the graph edge type
    *
    * @return The newly created edge if added to the graph, otherwise <code>
    * null</code>.
    */
```

Comment: Maybe just `remove_link_tag = re.sub(r'\s*{@link[^{}]*}', '', line)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, but could you post your answer with what needs to be removed. A bit confused here :)

Comment: Are you writing the modified contents back to another / same file? Your code is really confusing.

Comment: @AlyssaAlex code update done

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew does that matter whether I print the result or write it back to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sipmly as:

```
import re

input = """/**
    * Adds the specified source and target vertices to the graph, if not already included, and
    * creates a new edge and adds it to the specified graph similarly to the
    * {@link Graph#addEdge(Object, Object)} method.
    *
    * @param graph the graph for which the specified edge to be added
    * @param sourceVertex source vertex of the edge
    * @param targetVertex target vertex of the edge
    * @param <V> the graph vertex type
    * @param <E> the graph edge type
    *
    * @return The newly created edge if added to the graph, otherwise <code>
    * null</code>.
    */"""

out = re.sub('{@link.*?}', '', input)
```

Output:

```
/**
     * Adds the specified source and target vertices to the graph, if not already included, and
     * creates a new edge and adds it to the specified graph similarly to the
     *  method.
     *
     * @param graph the graph for which the specified edge to be added
     * @param sourceVertex source vertex of the edge
     * @param targetVertex target vertex of the edge
     * @param <V> the graph vertex type
     * @param <E> the graph edge type
     *
     * @return The newly created edge if added to the graph, otherwise <code>
     * null</code>.
     */
```

Comment: Hey thanks, sorry for not being clear, I just updated my question. I do not want to lose the content between my `{@code....}` tag

Comment: simply add @link into re.sub